# Associating data in a three.js mesh object - in a procedurally generated city

Tags: javascript, three.js, procedural-generation

I'm trying to create a procedurally generated city using three.js, which will primarily consist of buildings. A requirements is, when a building is clicked on (with a mouse) information about that building (e.g. name, location etc.) should be displayed - say, as a text box hovering next to that building.

I was trying to look if the three.js mesh object (that would represent a building) had any "data" property where this info can be stored. It doesn't.

Any idea how this functionality could be achieved? TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Object3D` class has a property `userData` where you can *safely* add custom data.

Since the `Mesh` class is derived from `Object3D`, it has that property, too.

Use it like so:

```
mesh.userData.name = "TheName";
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Its still JavaScript so you can add a custom object to the mesh:

```
var building = new THREE.Mesh( [...] );
building.info = { name: "myHouse", lat: 48.12, lng: 8.54, [...] };

console.log( building.info.name ); //myHouse
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out.